# Webpack usage without requirejs

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router, requirejs

I have given in webpack.config.js the entry point as my app.js with all my stateproviders but it is not loading the dependencies. So my question is thus.
By using webpack can we bundle angular ui without the use of requirejs ?

Comment: Welcome. Please help the community to help you by providing enough details about your specific problem. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: What are you asking, are you yourself clear about that?